# insert into & select

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

Всем привет!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MSG](
    [MSG_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [int] NOT NULL,
    [USER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MSG] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MSG_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

И требуется в таблицу вставить значения через select, но не выходит

Делаю так, но вместо MSG_ID не знаю что вставить :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MSG] ([MSG_ID], [NAME], [USER_ID])
SELECT [ЧТО СЮДА ?], [NAME], [USER_ID] FROM [dbo].[USERS] WHERE [dbo].[USERS].[DELETED] <> 1
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67103/discussion-on-question-by-noanother-insert-into-select).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ввиду того, что для хранения последнего ID (как было выяснено в переписке к вопросу) используется отдельная таблица, можно предложить только такое решение:

```
begin transaction;

update LAST_IDS set LAST_ID=LAST_ID where NAME = 'MSG';  -- Блокируем запись

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MSG] ([MSG_ID], [NAME], [USER_ID])
SELECT L.LAST_ID + row_number() over(order by (select NULL)),     -- Получаем ID
       U.NAME, U.USER_ID
  FROM [dbo].[USERS] U, LAST_IDS L
 WHERE [dbo].[USERS].[DELETED] <> 1
   AND L.NAME = 'MSG';

update LAST_IDS set LAST_ID=LAST_ID+@@ROWCOUNT
 where NAME = 'MSG';                    -- Меняем последний использованный ID
commit;
```

Comment: Вместо первого `update` можно вытащить `LAST_ID` в переменную с одновременной блокировкой --> `select @lastID = LAST_ID from LAST_IDS WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) where NAME = 'MSG';`, и в `insert` не обращаться повторно к `LAST_IDS`.

Comment: ещё поправка: `over(order by NULL)` --> `over(order by (SELECT NULL))`

Comment: @i-one Поправил. во извращенцы то MS с запретом констант в over ...

Comment: да, странный запрет, можно было бы и разрешить, переменные при этом разрешены

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас Sql Server 2012 версии и выше, Вы можете воспользоваться сиквенсами (SEQUENCE) - это объект БД, представляющий собой монотонный ряд чисел. Он имеет начальное значение и шаг.

Для использования его необходимо создать, задав имя, схему и набор параметров. Более подробное описание - по ссылке ниже:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql

Чтобы применить его в конструкции INSERT, воспользуйтесь следующим примером

```
INSERT Test.TestTable (CounterColumn,Name)  
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR %Название вашего сиквенса%, 'Syed') ;
```